# Composite video with 8-bit DAC

Tags: esp32, dac, programmable-logic

recently my eyes got caught by this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t1_XNc3vNw)

It shows how ESP32 can draw analog composite video using I2S -> DMA -> DAC.
I considered using this concept in my project but it has a little drawback. With this approach, you can achieve only 54 gray levels (179 if you step down DAC voltage from 3.3Vto 1V). 300mV of DAC's voltage is just "thrown out" by "blank level".

Is there any way I could achieve a better dynamic range using this setup (without using any external DAC)?

Comment: An opamp to squeeze the entire DAC range into your desired 300-1000 mV range?

Comment: opam + DC offset suggested by @winny is good idea. 256bit on 0.7V range gives around 3 mV per steps. Keep in mind if you want to be able to use that extra dynamic range efficently, you will have to mitigate the noise injection in your signal to less than 1.5 mV.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand this question, the DAC voltage range of the sync level should be reduced to give more dynamic room for the luminance values.

A small part of the DAC voltage range must still be reserved for the blanking information. I am not sure, if this increase in resulution of less than one bit is worth the effort.

So the assumed DAC signal here (DAC_OUT) contains a reduced blanking amplitude of 40 mV and the rest up to 3.3 V can be used for luminance. The idea of this circuit is to add a DC offset to the DAC signal. OA1 will buffers this. The MOSFET M1, that connects the signal to GND during blanking, reconstructs the required blanking amplitude.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJrAXw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A very fast comparator OA2 compares the DAC output with the blanking threshold created by R5/R6 (37 mV). In the blanking period M1 is conducting and forces OUT_1 to GND. This comparator needs only a single supply.

The voltage divider R3/R4 defines the head room of the voltage range, that will be used by the reconstructed blanking.

The voltage divider R7/R2 sets the analog peak value of 1 V.

The final video OpAmp OA3 has a gain of 2 to drive the video cable (R_LINE) with the proper impedance of 75 ohm used for analog video.

The simulator shows, how only a small part of the sine wave at the negative peak will be used to create the blanking. M1 must be a low capacitance RF type FET to keep the delay in the blanking signal as low as possible.

Comment: Thank you for detailed solution. Is there any explanation why exactly 37mV are selected?

Comment: @user3500960 No, there is no special reason. Lower values will give you more headroom for luminance, but there are offset errors in the comparator and stray capacitance, that may prevent a tue 0 V on the line, so you need some margin there.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I could achieve a better dynamic range using this setup (without using any external DAC)?

Not without some work.

The composite video signal extends from the sync tip to peak white.  No matter what comes out of the DAC, the signal eventually must produce 1 V (140 IRE units) across 75 ohms, including video, blanking, and sync.  If you have another I/O pin that can produce a digital signal that has all of the transitions in the composite sync waveform, synchronized to the video signal coming through the DAC, then this part of the output signal does not have to come through the DAC.  The same can be done with the blanking level.

So best case is three outputs from the uC: video through the DAC, logic-level sync pulse train, and logic-level blanking pulse train.  This frees up the full 255-step DAC range for the 92.5 IRE units of active video.  After that, the three signals are summed with various amounts of gain-scaling and DC offsets to recreate the complete composite signal.

If true broadcast quality is not required, you can drop the blanking signal and go with just the sync and video signals.

- OR -

You could use a second DAC channel to produce a scaled sync+blanking waveform that is simply offset and summed with the recovered video signal.  Since by definition the sync and blanking voltages never change during the active video portion of a horizontal line, it should take almost zero extra uC bandwidth to drive two DAC channels in this manner.